# turn off mod_rewrite for subdirectory

Tags: mod-rewrite

In httpd.conf, I have a rewrite rule in the webroot

first, I turn off mod_rewrite in the subdirectory

```
<directory /home/xxxx/public_html/subdir>
  RewriteEngine off
</directory>
```

then turn on where needed

```
<directory /home/xxxx/public_html>
  RewriteEngine On
  # bunch of rewrite rules
</directory>
```

But rewrite engine remains on in subdir. I've done logging with RewriteLog 3 and see it processing files in subdir.

I've tried moving the subdir  below the main directory section in httpd.conf but still it processes subdir files.

I know I could match and exclude the subdir in my main rules, but I'm trying to avoid the processing of that directory at all for speed.

Any ideas why or how to turn off mod_rewrite for a subdirectory?

Comment: If it's on for the root, the rules there will always be tested even if they interfere with normal URLs in a subdir. You're better off moving the rules to the vhost level, adding some type of exclude for the subdir, and turning off allowoverride. This means the rules stay in memory and the performance is improved by the server not looking for and re-parsing htaccess files.